# Find the same weekday last year in DAX

Tags: dax

I would like to have a DAX equivalent of the following SQL code:

```
SELECT DATEADD(week, -52, '2018-05-05')
--Result: 2017-05-06 00:00:00.000
```

2018-05-05 was a Saturday, I would like to see the same Saturday for the previous year: 2017-05-06 (as shown on the the SQL above)

In DAX, the DATEADD method allows to add/subtract by year, quarter, month and day intervals only. Is there any other function that allows to add or subtract weeks? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just add `-52*7` days?

Comment: Actually.. yes. this works! Thank you @AlexisOlson